# Why does first-of-type not target the first of my footnotes?

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why the above is not making the text red.

Here is a link to my project: [www.jordy.news](https://www.jordy.news)

```css
article p i.note:first-of-type {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p>
    An example<i>¹</i> sentence with some<i>²</i> notes.
    <br><br>
    <i class="note">1. Some information.</I>
    <br>
    <i class="note">2. Some more information.</i>
  </p>
</article>
```

Comment: I often encounter this problem. That's why I create a small JS code that solves this problem. If this works for you, I will post the JS code in answer to your question

Comment: That is kind of you. What I think I'll do I use <sup> and <sub> and then hopefully will be able to call the firs-of-type that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the text (`An example<i>¹</i> sentence with some<i>²</i> notes.`) in a tag, for example, in a `span`, in order to ignore it in css when referring to the first `i.note`.

You can refer to the second selector like this:

```
article p:not(span) > i.note:first-of-type {
  color:red;
}
```

```css
article p:not(span) > i.note:first-of-type {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p>
    <span>An example<i>¹</i> sentence with some<i>²</i> notes.</span> 
    <i class="note">1. Some information.</i>
    <i class="note">2. Some more information.</i>
  </p>
</article>
```

Comment: Although Quentin answered my question (Thank you) you were the most helpful in finding a solution and solving my problem.

Comment: I was glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

`first-of-type` means exactly that. It doesn't mean `first-of-everything-else-the-selector-says`.

The first element of type `i` in the paragraph is `<i>¹</i>`, which doesn't match the `.note` part of the selector.